# UITextField as sublayer

Tags: iphone, ipad, calayer

I am adding a UITextField's layer as a sublayer to an existing layer that is actually a UIImageView. I apply perspective rotation on the image view and it works fine. But the UITextField does not become active. The beginFirstResponder message to it does not show the keyboard. Tapping it doesn't work, it stays inactive from user interaction. I also tried setting the zPosition for the textfield's layer so that it is above the imageview layer and it's zPosition.

```
    rightband = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right-band.png"]];
    rightband.layer.frame = CGRectMake(623.5, 310.5, 624, 210);
    rightband.layer.zPosition = 40.0f;


    usernameField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 260, 26)];
    usernameField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    usernameField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    usernameField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    usernameField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    usernameField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    usernameField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:17];
    usernameField.textColor = UIColorFromRGB(0x303030);
    usernameField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    usernameField.placeholder = @"Username";
    usernameField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    usernameField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
    usernameField.delegate = self;
    usernameField.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);
    usernameField.layer.zPosition = 100.0f;
    usernameField.layer.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 260, 26); 
    [rightband.layer addSublayer:usernameField.layer];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the text field view in order for it to respond to touches. 
So do :

```
[rightband addSubview:usernameField];
```

Comment: Right. I figured that much. But then I animate the rightband (perspective rotation). Applying the sublayer transform doesn't work until it is a sublayer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to change the view heirarchy to the following

UIView -> UIImageView and UITextField
Dont add the UITextField as a child to UIImageView
The UITextField and UIImageView will be both child's to a UIView